# Почему не обособляется деепричастный оборот?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

1. Мужество похоже на добродетель, повинуясь которой люди совершают прекрасные дела.

Здесь деепричастие имеет в качестве зависимого слова союзное слово *который* в составе придаточного определительного предложения,такое деепричастие от придаточного предложения запятой не отделяется.

2. Инструменты, играть на которых нужно вдувая в них воздух, называются духовыми.

Здесь деепричастный оборот не обособляется, потому что является смысловым центром определительного предложения?

Answer (score 3):

Деепричастие тесно примыкает к сказуемому по смыслу: нужно играть вдувая. Поэтому оборот не обособляется.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Инструменты, играть на которых нужно вдувая в них воздух, называются духовыми. Запятой перед деепричастием НЕТ, но ее отсутствие объясняется НЕ ТЕСНОЙ СВЯЗЬЮ ДЕЕПРИЧАСТИЯ И СКАЗУЕМОГО, А НАЛИЧИЕМ ДВУХ ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ ОБОРОТОВ.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Попробуем перестроить  предложение: На духовых инструментах нужно играть, вдувая в них воздух.Запятая, кажется,  ставится? И тесной связи нет.

Думаю, что здесь дело не в тесной связи, а в сильном управлении деепричастия, находящегося ВНУТРИ ДРУГОГО ОБОСОБЛЕННОГО ОБОРОТА.

Comment: Вера, одни и те же обороты могут обособляться в зависимости от места в предложении. Ср.: По дорожке сада он шел **не оглядываясь**. — **Не оглядываясь**, он шел по дорожке сада. Такое обособление подчеркивает усиление глагольности (обозначении      действия).                                                                                                                                                                                                                     См.: Полный академический справочник.

Comment: Серж, более того. Можно просто слегка распространить предложение, и оборот уже можно будет обособить:  "Он еще  очень долго  шел по дорожке сада, не оглядываясь". Всё зависит от структуры предложения и от расстановки в нем фразовых ударений. В нашем же предложении на"играть" падает ударение, а после ударения обязательно делается пауза, вот и не обойтись без запятой.

Comment: Вера, если перестроить предложение, запятая может и нужна будет. Но только не в таком порядке, как в примере автора.

Comment: Серж, я исправляю ответ. Мне кажется, что меня неправильно поняли

Comment: Вера, в том предложении, которое вы привели в пояснении, запятая действительно нужна.